# Does Git view my local repository as unique

Tags: git

Pretty basic question, but I have a web project using Git version control, involving 3 git repos.

1. My local repo
2. repo hosted on Bitbucket
3. Repo on production server

I am planning on trying some risky changes to my local git repo - which may end up corrupting or breaking git's functionality locally.
My question is, if I mess up my local git repo, is it possible to simply delete the entire project folder containing the git repo and the working files, and simply clone from one of the other good repos?
Specifically, Im wondering if git system has somehow identified my local repo as unique, either by username, repo name or machine etc, such that if I was to clone from another machine and start pushing I could get errors like:

- error: trying to use git repo "belonging to" `machine x` on `machine y`

I suspect git may not care, and simply accept pushes from the new local repo, but if git does complain, is it possible to re-configure the newly cloned local repo or perform some other such workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, if I mess up my local git repo, is it possible to simply delete the entire project folder containing the git repo and the working files, and simply clone from one of the other good repos?

Yes. As long as you don't push, the other repositories are unaffected.

> Specifically, I'm wondering if git system has somehow identified my local repo as unique.

The directory into which you clone the repository is what makes it unique.

> I suspect git may not care, and simply accept pushes from the new local repo

Sure. It does of course check that the push doesn't cause any conflicts.

> but if git does complain, is it possible to re-configure the newly cloned local repo or perform some other such workaround?

You can use the [git remote](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) command to update or change the push URL, but if you don't move the remote, it's unlikely you'll ever need to.

Comment: One of my favorite things about git is that I can try out 'risky things' on my local repo and not worry about any errors bleeding over to the main shared repo.

Comment: @Barend - great, concise answer, - yes your assumptions were all correct as I understood them , e.g. `assuming the risky stuff wasnt pushed to other machines` and `push from new local repo doesnt cause any "normal" conflict issues` thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this question is very clear, but if I understand you correctly, you just don't want to break Git.  Git is stupid software that can do great things.  As long as the user doesn't do "stupid" things, then they're golden `:)`  You can play around local all you want without worry of breaking.  It's when you fiddle with `pull`, `merge` and `push` that you could potentially run into errors.

One thing you could do, if you haven't already done, is setup your local repository to have all remotes, then you can push/pull to each of them individually.  Observe.

```
$ git init 
$ git remote add dev http://bitbucket.org/repo
$ git remote add prod https://prod/repo
```

Now you can make changes locally, and you shouldn't have to worry about git getting "corrupted".

Once done with development, push the changes to the desired remote.

```
$ git push dev branch
```

Comment: It's a great design.  Also worth noting that with this design, if you need to pull in a change that someone else made from dev, you can do `git pull dev branch` or from the `prod` repo respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, you can have different version of your project on git, because it can save the state of your program at different points. One of the many wonderful things about git is it is a distributed revision control system, when used properly it will help you save versions of your code that you can undo easily or even redo when you get better at understanding it. It has a high learning curve to master, but you can start using it with a few simple commands.

I recommend doing a git tutorial to get acquainted with it: https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

> Specifically, Im wondering if git system has somehow identified my
>   local repo as unique, either by username, repo name or machine etc,
>   such that if I was to clone from another machine and start pushing I
>   could get errors like:
>
> ```
> error: trying to use git repo "belonging to" machine x on machine y
> ```

Yes, if you have cloned someones project from github then your project copy is local to your computer. You can then set up your own repository and then 'push' your changes to save them for your own purposes.

Comment: from the OP's question, it sounds like they are familiar with Git, I'm not sure they'll need the trygit tutorial `:)`  They probably come from SVN or some other SCM where any action, could make or break your entire source.

Comment: @sircapsalot is right, I use git regularly and the question is pretty basic, but this is a non-familiar git process - and the project represents many months of work, so I was especially keen to get advice from community. tutorial is pretty interesting though, thanks

Comment: No problem. Feel free to vote it up if it was helpful at all.